# How to add my own Authentication with cookies in ASP.Net Core Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httpcontext

I have been despairing for almost a week now. I am currently writing a website in C # and decided against an MVC Page (because I do not quite understand that ...).
Therefore, I have chosen a simple web application (Visual Studio 2017) and I am fine with that until now. I have classes like in normal WPF applications and I manage quite well so far.
My problem: I just cannot save cookie or session variables. I can already read cookies, as well as almost everything else - only writing is not possible.
(If not everything is clear to you: I am still a relative newbee who used to build websites in PHP.)
Btw: Sorry for my possible bad English.

Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Webpage {
    public class Startup {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
            if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error/500");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseStaticHttpContext();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
    public static class StaticHttpContextExtensions {
        public static void AddHttpContextAccessor(this IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        }

        public static IApplicationBuilder UseStaticHttpContext(this IApplicationBuilder app) {
            var httpContextAccessor = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            System.Web.HttpContext.Configure(httpContextAccessor);
            return app;
        }
    }
}

namespace System.Web {
    public static class HttpContext {
        private static IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext Current => _contextAccessor.HttpContext;

        internal static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) {
            _contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }
    }
}
```

HttpConnection.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Webpage.Classes {
    public class HttpConnection {
        public static IPAddress GetUserIPAddress() {
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        }

        public static string addReplaceCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue) {
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Append(cookieName, cookieValue, new CookieOptions {
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
                Domain = null
            });
            return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("cookieName")) ?

Comment: I've tried that too, but there's no Class called HttpCookie (or similar). And I cannot use the method Add in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies for any reason.